# Django using curry to build formsets with custom form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a question on the use of the curry function in Django. I've used it successfully to build an inlinemodelformset with a custom Form thus:

```
person_obj, formed = Mother.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
FormSetClass = inlineformset_factory(Mother, Relation, form=RelationForm, extra=1)
FormSetClass.form = staticmethod(curry(RelationForm, person=person_obj))
```

What this does is enable me to pass in the person to the kwargs in the forms init method, to filter the querysets:

```
class RelationForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         person = kwargs.pop('person')
         qs = Relation.objects.filter(person=person)
         self.fields['my-field'].queryset = qs
```

My question is that I have no clue how this works - I can't find any documentation on it, and the source code doesn't really shed any light on it for me. Can anyone explain how this works, and give some good use cases for curry, apart from this one?

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice example in Pro Django book of how curry works.

Simply it lets you take function with pre-defined arguments and save it as a new function to use later only with needed arguments. All this **without** running the function.

For the above case curry is a huge help, since we don't need to instantiate RelationForm just to pass through the person argument.